# Drawing QImage on a QPainter which has inverted y-axis

Tags: qt, graphics

I have a scene with an inverted y-axis. Everything is correctly drawn except QImages.

I use `drawIage()` as:

```
QRectF aWorldRect = ...
QRectF anImageRect = QRectF(0, 0, theQImage.width(), theQImage.height())
thePainter->drawImage(aWorldRect, theQImage, anImageRect;
```

I get undefined graphics outside (to the top of) where the image should be displayed. This is normal because y-axis is inverted. So I expected something like that may fix the issue:

```
QRectF anImageRect = QRectF(0, 0, imgWidth, -imgHeight)
```

It has the same effect. If I do `aWorldRect = aWorldRect.noralized()` before calling `drawImage()`, I get the image in the correct rectangle but **mirrored** so I did `aQImage = aQImage.mirrored()`. Now the image is correctly displayed in the correct rectangle

I consider this a workaround which I don't like to keep. So, can someone tell me what should be done to get the image displayed, the right way?

**Update**
Here I put a minimal sample of my problem that is ready to compile:

**Update 2014-04-09 10:05 EET**
Updated the sample code little bit to make really work using the workaround

```
#include <QtGui>

const int WIDTH = 640;
const int HEIGHT = 480;

class View : public QGraphicsView
{
protected:
    void drawBackground(QPainter *p, const QRectF & rect)
    {
        QImage img = QImage("/usr/share/backgrounds/images/stone_bird.jpg"); // or any other

        /* The next three lines makes everything displayed correctly but
           should be considered a workaround */
        /* I ignore the rect that is passed to the function on purpose  */
        QRectF imageRect = QRectF(QPointF(0, 0), QPointF(img.width(), img.height()));
        QRectF theSceneRect = sceneRect().normalized();
        p->drawImage(theSceneRect, img.mirrored(), imageRect);

    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    View w;

    /* I don't want to change the code below */
    w.setScene(new QGraphicsScene(QRectF(QPointF(0, HEIGHT), QPointF(WIDTH, 0))));
    w.scale(1, -1);
    w.scene()->addLine(0, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 0);
    w.showMaximized();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What is `aWorldRect`? Can you show, how do you calculate it?

Comment: It is a rectangle that is compatible with the scene; the top value is greater than the bottom

Comment: You can save image mirrored already, or you can draw background as `GraphicsItem` with `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag set

Comment: Yes, but this will still be a workaround. I just want to make it the right way

Comment: @mmonem what do you mean by right way? Y-axis is flipped. So any other paintings will be done using that trasformation. You can scale it back. But you are not able to change code in main() function, as I understand

Comment: I believe there is small & light something (like playing with matrices) to be done in order to make the correct display of the image without the need for mirroring which is very expensive if the image is too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated on 2014-04-14 14:35 EET**

I could finally solve the problem *reliably* by replacing the two lines

```
QRectF theSceneRect = sceneRect().normalized();
p->drawImage(theSceneRect, img.mirrored(), imageRect);
```

of my question to

```
QRectF theSceneRect = sceneRect(); // Not normalized. It is no more workaround :)

qreal x = theSceneRect.x();
qreal y = theSceneRect.y();
qreal w = theSceneRect.width();
qreal h = theSceneRect.height();
qreal sx = imageRect.x();
qreal sy = imageRect.y();
qreal sw = imageRect.width();
qreal sh = imageRect.height();

p->translate(x, y);
p->scale(w / sw, h / sh);
p->setBackgroundMode(Qt::TransparentMode);
p->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, p->renderHints() &
    QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
QBrush brush(img);
p->setBrush(brush);
p->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
p->setBrushOrigin(QPointF(-sx, -sy));
p->drawRect(QRectF(0, 0, sw, sh));

p->restore();
```

This is inspired by the implementation of the `QPainter::drawImage()` which is not reliable in such cases due to many *if* statements handling rectangles with negative values of width or height.

It would be better if I made the solution in another function but I kept it this way to be more compatible with the code in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The approach of reversing the Y coordinate value is right but the implementation was faulty.

[QRectF](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qrectf.html)'s documentation shows that it takes (x, y, width, height). Giving height as negative makes little sense. Instead try the other constructor which takes *topLeft* and *bottomRight*.

```
QRectF anImageRect(QPointF(0.0f, -imgHeight), QPointF(imageWidth, 0.0f));
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that the only drawings like line, arc, etc. are affected by the scale (1, -1) transform you set on the view. `drawImage` continues to render upside down due to the scale set. The simple fix is to set the scale back to (1, -1). Here's the updated code:

```
void drawBackground(QPainter *p, const QRectF & rect)
{
    QImage img = QImage("/usr/share/backgrounds/images/stone_bird.jpg");

    // backup the current transform set (which has the earlier scale of (1, -1))
    const QTransform oldTransform = p->transform();

    // set the transform back to identity to make the Y axis go from top to bottom
    p->setTransform(QTransform());
    // draw
    QRectF theSceneRect = sceneRect().normalized();
    p->drawImage(theSceneRect, img);

    // revert back to the earlier transform
    p->setTransform(oldTransform);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, it is the same

Comment: Did you also try `QRectF anImageRect(QPointF(0.0f, imgHeight), QPointF(imageWidth, 0.0f));`?

Comment: yes, the same. I am making a sample program of my problem

Comment: I updated the answer for the edited question. I've tested the code myself, it works.

Comment: Did you test my code or my code with your modifications?

Comment: First just your code, which didn't draw anything despite finding the file correctly; then I made modifications on your code and it rendering with the correct side up.

Comment: Thank you for your trails. Actually simple resetting the transform cant be enough because the transform has more than just the scale(-1, 1)

Comment: Also, I tried adding a temporary `scale (-1, 1)` prior to drawing the image to compensate the old `scale(-1, 1)`. It does not work, too